# read data character by character from file in assembly GAS compiler

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm writing an assembly program with GAS compiler and AT&T syntax.

I have 2 files: one to read from and another one to write in.
From terminal i launch the program in this way: `./myprogram inputfile.txt outputfile.txt`

Now I want to read input data character by character and this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
.section .data
  buff_size: .long 1

.section .bss
  .lcomm buff, 18

.section  .text              # declaring our .text segment
  .globl _start              # telling where program execution should start

_start:

    popl %eax       # Get the number of arguments
    popl %ebx       # Get the program name
    popl %ebx       # Get the first actual argument - file to read

    # open the file
    movl $5, %eax       # open
    movl $0, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80       

    # read the file

    movl $0, %esi

    # these 6 instructions read first character from inputfile.txt
    movl %eax, %ebx     # file_descriptor,
    movl $3, %eax       
    movl $buff, %edi    
    leal (%esi,%edi,1), %ecx    
    movl buff_size, %edx
    int $0x80

    # these 6 instructions can't read the second character from inputfile.txt and I can't understand why.
    movl $1, %esi
    movl $3, %eax       
    movl $buff, %edi    
    leal (%esi,%edi,1), %ecx    
    movl buff_size, %edx
    int $0x80


    # open the file
    popl %ebx       # Get the second actual argument - file to write
    movl $5, %eax       # open
    movl $2, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80       

    # write to STDOUT
    movl %eax, %ebx     # file_descriptor
    movl $4, %eax       
    leal buff, %ecx     
    movl buff_size, %edx    
    int $0x80       

    # exit
    movl $1, %eax       
    movl $0, %ebx       
    int $0x80
```

This piece of code read the first character from inputfile.txt successfully and it writes that character inside outputfile.txt...

Now I want to read and write the second character but it doesn't work as suggested in the comment I've written through the code.

FYI:

OS: Ubuntu 14 - 64 bit
Compiler: GAS

My inputfile.txt looks so: `4,3,55,15,8,9`

Comment: You only write the first character out, no matter that you read 2.

Comment: Hint: use `strace ./a.out` to trace programs that make system calls.