# read and write to file assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have an inputfile.txt which looks like this: `3 4 2 0 8 1 5 3`

I'm trying to write inside an `outputfile.txt` each character of inputfile incremented by 1. 
So inside outputfile.txt I should see `4 5 3 1 9 2 6 4`.
I have tried to write this piece of code but I have several doubts.

```
.section .data
  buff_size: .long 18

.section .bss
  .lcomm buff, 18

.section  .text              # declaring our .text segment
  .globl _start              # telling where program execution should start

_start:

    popl %eax       # Get the number of arguments
    popl %ebx       # Get the program name
    popl %ebx       # Get the first actual argument - file to read

    # open the file
    movl $5, %eax       # open 
    movl $0, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80        

    # read the file

    movl $0, %esi
    movl %eax, %ebx     # file_descriptor

    analyzecharacter:   #here I want to read a single character
        movl $3, %eax       
        movl $buff, %edi    
        leal (%esi,%edi,1), %ecx    
        movl $1, %edx
        int $0x80
        add $1, %esi #this point is not clear to me, what I'd like to do is to increment the index of the buffer in order to be positioned on the next cell of buffer array, I've added 1 but I think is not correct
        cmp $8, %esi  # if I've read all 8 characters then I'll exit
        je exit

    openoutputfile:
    popl %ebx       # Get the second actual argument - file to write
    movl $5, %eax       # open
    movl $2, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80       

    writeinoutputfile:
    #increment by 1 and write the character to STDOUT
    movl %eax, %ebx     # file_descriptor
    movl $4, %eax       
    leal (%esi,%edi,1), %ecx
    add $1, %ecx #increment by 1        
    movl $1, %edx   
    int $0x80
    jmp analyzecharacter        

    exit:
    movl $1, %eax       
    movl $0, %ebx       
    int $0x80
```

I have 2 problems/doubts:

1- my first doubt is about this instruction: `add $1, %esi`. Is this the right way to move through `buffer` array?

2- The second doubt is: When I analyze each character should I always invoke `openoutputfile` label? I think that in this way I'm reopening the file and the previous content is overwritten.
Indeed if I run the program I see only a single character `\00` (a garbage  character, caused by the value of %esi in this instruction I guess: `leal (%esi,%edi,1), %ecx` ).

I hope my problems are clear, I'm pretty new to assembly and I've spent several hours on this.

```
FYI: 
I'm using GAS Compiler and the syntax is AT&T.
Moreover I'm on Ubuntu 64 bit and Intel CPU.
```

Comment: Can you summarize the difference between this code + question and [the previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931187/read-data-character-by-character-from-file-in-assembly-gas-compiler), to save time for those of us who already looked at it?

Comment: Does this code work?  i.e. is this a code-review question?  Or is there still a bug you need help with?  (And no I haven't read it yet, just glanced.  I might read it in detail later.)

Comment: Here I'm trying to create a loop that iterates over each character inside buffer while in the previous version I tried to read only the first and the second character without using a loop. In this case I have 8 character but probably my inputfile.txt will have more than 8 next times.

Comment: No this code doesn't work, because my outputfile.txt has "\00" character after program execution

Comment: If you have a buffer, why do you want to read one character at a time?  Why not write a normal program that `read`s a full buffer (or EOF), loops over the buffer, then `write`s the buffer to an output file?  Reading a single character at a time only makes sense if you reuse the same single-byte buffer for every read+write pair (and then you don't need `inc %esi`.

Comment: Did you try `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls it makes?  And did you use `gdb` to step through the code?  Do you know why it doesn't do what you want, but aren't sure how to fix it?  Or are you still looking for the logic error?

Comment: I've already written a program which reads the entire buffer and writes it inside another file, but I don't  know if you noticed that the difference between this version and the previous (easiest to me) one is that here I need to increment each character by 1 while in the previous I just copied the characters

Comment: So use your progam that reads a whole buffer, and add a loop over the buffer doing `addl $0x01010101, (%esi)` / `add $4, %esi`.  (If the buffer contains only ASCII text, none of the adds can overflow into the next byte, so you can and should use SIMD.  This is a simple SWAR, but you could also use SSE2 `paddb`).  Never `read`ing a byte at a time unless you need to (e.g. to avoid reading too much from a tty), because system calls are expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, how I would do the code...
Thinking about it, I'm so used to Intel syntax, that I'm unable to write AT&T source from my head on the web without bugs (and I'm too lazy to actually do the real thing and debug it), so I will try to avoid writing instructions completely and just describe the process, to let you fill up the instructions.

So let's decide you want to do it char by char, version 1 of my source:

```
start:
  ; verify the command line has enough parameters, if not jump to exitToOs
  ; open both input and output files at the start of the code
processingLoop:
  ; read single char
  ; if no char was read (EOF?), jmp finishProcessing
  ; process it
  ; write it
  jmp processingLoop
finishProcessing:
  ; close both input and output files
exitToOs:
  ; exit back to OS
```

- now "run" it in your mind, verify all the major branch points make sense and will handle correctly for all major corner cases.
- make sure you understand how the code will work, where it will loop, and where and why it will break out of loop.
- make sure there's no infinite loop, or leaking of resources

After going trough my checklist, there's one subtle problem with this design, it's not rigorously checking file system errors, like failing to open either of the files, or writing the character (but your source doesn't care either). Otherwise I think it should work well.

So let's extend it in version 2 to be more close to real ASM instructions (asterisk marked instructions are by me, so probably with messed syntax, it's up to you to make final version of those):

```
start:
  ; verify the command line has enough parameters, if not jump to exitToOs
    popl %eax       # Get the number of arguments
   * cmpl $3,eax   ; "./binary fileinput fileoutput" will have $3 here?? Debug!
   * jnz exitToOs

  ; open both input and output files at the start of the code
    movl $5, %eax       # open 
    popl %ebx       # Get the program name

  ; open input file first
    popl %ebx       # Get the first actual argument - file to read
    movl $0, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80
    cmpl $-1, %eax  ; valid file handle?
    jz exitToOs
   * movl %eax, ($varInputHandle) ; store input file handle to memory

  ; open output file, make it writable, create if not exists
    movl $5, %eax       # open 
    popl %ebx       # Get the second actual argument - file to write
   * ; next two lines should use octal numbers, I hope the syntax is correct
   * movl $0101, %ecx # create flag + write only access (if google is telling me truth)
   * movl $0666, %edx ; permissions for out file as rw-rw-rw-
    int $0x80
    cmpl $-1, %eax  ; valid file handle?
    jz exitToOs
    movl %eax, ($varOutputHandle) ; store output file handle to memory

processingLoop:

  ; read single char to varBuffer
    movl $3, %eax
    movl ($varInputHandle), %ebx
    movl $varBuffer, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

  ; if no char was read (EOF?), jmp finishProcessing
    cmpl $0, %eax
    jz finishProcessing ; looks like total success, finish cleanly

  ;TODO process it
   * incb ($varBuffer) ; you wanted this IIRC?

  ; write it
    movl $4, %eax       
    movl ($varOutputHandle), %ebx     # file_descriptor
    movl $varBuffer, %ecx  ; BTW, still set from char read, so just for readability
    movl $1, %edx    ; this one is still set from char read too
    int $0x80

  ; done, go for the next char
    jmp processingLoop

finishProcessing:
    movl $0, ($varExitCode) ; everything went OK, set exit code to 0

exitToOs:
  ; close both input and output files, if any of them is opened
    movl ($varOutputHandle), %ebx     # file_descriptor
    call closeFile
    movl ($varInputHandle), %ebx
    call closeFile

  ; exit back to OS
    movl $1, %eax
    movl ($varExitCode), %ebx
    int $0x80

closeFile:
    cmpl $-1, %ebx
    ret z ; file not opened, just ret
    movl $6, %eax  ; sys_close
    int $0x80
    ; returns 0 when OK, or -1 in case of error, but no handling here
    ret

.data
varExitCode: dd 1 ; no idea about AT&T syntax, "dd" is "define dword" in NASM
  ; default value for exit code is "1" (some error)
varInputHandle: dd -1 ; default = invalid handle
varOutputHandle: dd -1 ; default = invalid handle
varBuffer: db ? ; (single byte buffer)
```

Whoa, I actually wrote it fully? (of course it needs the syntax check + cleanup of asterisks, and ";" for comments, etc...)

But I mean, the comments from version 1 were already so detailed, that each required only handful of ASM instructions, so it was not that difficult (although now I see I did submit the first answer 53min ago, so this was about ~1h of work for me (including googling and a bit of other errands elsewhere)).

And I absolutely don't get how some human may want to use AT&T syntax, which is so ridiculously verbose. I can easily understand why the GCC is using it, for compilers this is perfectly fine.

But maybe you should check NASM, which is "human" oriented (to write only as few syntax sugar, as possible, and focus on instructions). The major problem (or advantage in my opinion) with NASM is Intel syntax, e.g. `MOV eax,ebx` puts number `ebx` into `eax`, which is Intels fault, taking `LD` syntax from other microprocessors manufacturers, ignoring the *LD = load* meaning, and changing it to *MOV = move* to not blatantly copy the instruction set.

Then again, I have absolutely no idea why `ADD $1,%eax` is the correct way in AT&T (instead of `eax,1` order), and I don't even want to know, but it doesn't make any sense to me (the reversed `MOV` makes at least some sense due to `LD` origins of Intel's `MOV` syntax).

OTOH I can relate to `cmp $number,%reg` since I started to use "yoda" formatting in C++ to avoid variable value changes by accident in `if` (compare: `if (0 = variable)` vs `if (variable = 0)`, both having typo `=` instead of wanted `==` .. the "yoda" one will not compile even with warnings OFF).

But ... oh.. this is my last AT&T ASM answer for this week, it annoys hell out of me. (I know this is personal preference, but all those additional `$` and `%` annoys me just as much, as the reversed order).

---

Please, I spend serious amount of time writing this. Try to spend serious time studying it, and trying to understand it. If confused, ask in comments, but it would be pitiful waste of our time, if you would completely miss the point and not learn anything useful from this. :) So keep on.

---

Final note: and search hard for some debugger, find something what suits you well (probably some visual one like old "TD" from Borland in DOS days would be super nice for newcomer), but it's **absolutely essential** for you to improve quickly, to be able to step instruction by instruction over the code, and watch how the registers and memory content do change values. Really, if you would be able to debug your own code, you would soon realize you are reading second character from wrong file handle in `%ebx`... (at least I hope so).

Comment: thank you, my ideas are more clear now. I'll try to write it from scratch following your answer. Btw I have to do with AT&T and I can't choose another syntax.

Comment: let me know how it goes, especially if you don't understand why something works (or does not). About AT&T, yeah, then live with it. At least you will have easier time to decipher GCC compiler `.s` output than me, that's sometimes super handy, when you are profiling C/C++ for performance reasons.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, but I tried to add another step. I want to stop to read the file until I find a number which is equal to 3. So I added this 2 lines: "cmp $3, varBuffer"  "je exitToOs" after this line you wrote: * incb ($varBuffer).
So if I have a 2 it will be incremented to 3 and my program should go to exitToOS but this doesn't happen it will continue to loop until the EOF.

Comment: @GreenMamba: please, google "ASCII table", have it along while reading further. CPU is storing information in *bits*. `0` or `1`. It groups them usually by 8 (*byte*), 16 (x86: *word*), 32 (double word aka *dword*), 64 (*qword* from quad), ... For CPU a number $3 is a real number 3 (value 3). It has no visual (character) meaning for computer. To put human readable string at screen, an "character encoding" has to be used, lately utf-8 is popular because of it's versatility, but the code in the answer works in ASCII encoding. Now look at the ASCII table, and check value 3, and value 51 (33h).

Comment: @GreenMamba: the "incb" is *increment byte*. Byte is 8 bits, that's a 0..255 value (or -128 to 127 when highest bit is sign). Check the input file in some hex view (or in debugger after reading the single char from disk), you will see that the '2' from your file is ASCII encoded as value `50`. After incrementing it it will become `51` (which is character '3' in ASCII, how neat!). And '9' in input file will turn into ':' (try it)! So your test should be `cmpb` (byte variant!) `$51` ("3" in ASCII) `,($varBuffer)` (value at varBuffer address). You can also write it as `cmpb $'3',($varBuffer)`

Comment: @GreenMamba: note the `$'single ASCII char'` variant of constant, it helps to keep source human readable. Other option with ASCII digits is to use hexadecimal numbers, as `'0'` = `48` (decimal) = `0x30` or `30h` (hex), all of them supported by most of the assemblers. So with hex the ASCII value of digit `i` is `0x3i`. ... Your `cmp $3, varBuffer` compares value 3 (not '3') of 32b size (default size of address pointers in 32b mode) with varBuffer address (not value at address!). Read again some tutorials to fully grasp concept of memory and huge difference between `$buf` vs `($buf)`. `je` is OK

Comment: @GreenMamba: And again it clearly shows you don't debug, otherwise it would be in front of your eyes, that `cmp $3,$0xSomeHugeNumber` is never equal, thus it will never jump early to exit. Get some debugger, and start going instruction by instruction over the working version, which you think you understand, and watch the CPU registers and memory. Until you really understand it. Also I would rather do `je finishProcessing` than `je exitToOs`, if reaching '2' in input file is correct state. Jumping to `finishProcessing` will make the app return with exit code `0` (usual "no error" value).

Comment: 4 comments over additional 2 lines :/ ... push harder, I feel like you are getting hang of it, but push harder, reread basics, recheck your previous tries. It's not easy to please me, but you can do better than this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear 1) early: `add $1, %esi` is indeed equivalent to `inc %esi`.

While you are learning assembler, I would go for the `inc` variant, so you don't forget about its existence and get used to it. Back in 286-586 times it would be also faster to execute, today the `add` is used instead - because of the complexity of micro architecture (μops), where `inc` is tiny fraction more complicated for CPU (translating it back to add μops I guess, but you shouldn't worry about this while learning basics, aim rather for "human" readability of the source, do not any performance tricks yet).

Is it the right way?

Well, you should firstly decide whether you want to parse it per character (or rather go for `byte`, as character is nowadays often utf8 glyph, which can have size from 1 to 6 or how many bytes; I'm not even sure) OR to process it with buffers.

Your mix of the two is making it easy to do additional mistakes in the code.

From a quick look I see:

- you read only single byte per syscall, yet you store it at new place
  in buffer+counter (why? Just use single byte buffer, if you work per byte)
- when counter is 8, you exit (not processing the 8th
  read byte at all).
- you lose forever your input file descriptor after opening output file first time by popl %ebx (leaking file handles is very bad)
- then second char is read from output file (reusing the file handle from write)
- then you popl %ebx again, but there's no third parameter on command line, i.e. you fetch undefined memory from stack
- indeed you reopen the output file each time, so unless it's in append mode, it will overwrite content.

That's probably all major blunders you did, but that's actually so many, that I would suggest you to start over from scratch.

I will try to do a quick my version in next answer (as this one is getting a bit long), to show you how I would do it. But at first please try (hard) to find all the points I did highlight above, and understand how your code works. If you will fully understand what your instructions do, and why they really do the error I described, you will have much easier time to design your next code, plus debugging it. So the more of the points you will really find, and fully understand, the better for you.

---

"BTW notes":

I never did linux asm programming (I'm now itching to do something after reading about your effort), but from some wiki about system calls I read:

> All registers are preserved during the syscall.

Except return value in `eax` of course.

Keep this in mind, it may save you some hassle with repeating register setup before call, if you group syscalls appropriately.